# How to change image border and text simultaneously on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I am building a Netflix Clone just as a personal project.

On the Netflix Profiles section on hover, the border around the image and the user's name both get highlighted.

When I attempt with my code, on hover, the border and text change separately. I tried multiple ways for a little over hour without success. I know I'm missing something simplistic, and probably overthinking but I'm not sure how to approach this whether I create a JavaScript function perhaps, or within the CSS. (I am struggling with adding JS to my projects which is why I am building this clone!)?

*Tips or hints would be awesome as I am still trying to problem solve it*

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: -11px;
    margin-left: 22.5px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(17, 17, 17);
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
}

/* 
----------------
PROFILES SECTION
----------------
*/

.profiles {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}


.prfImg {
    margin: -6px;
    padding: 12px;
}

.prfImg > img {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 0.5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.061);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.prfImg > img:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.787);
    border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.787);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#user {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: grey;
}

/* 
----------------
BUTTON
----------------
*/

.btn {
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 22px; 
    color: grey;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1.5px solid grey;
}

button:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.863);
    border: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.863);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="profiles.css">
    <!-- google font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>NETFLIX - Profiles</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <img src="Img_d.profiles/netflix_logo.png" alt="netflix logo TM" width="99.2px">
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-text">
            <h1 style="font-size: 50px;">Who's watching?</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="profiles">
            <div class="prfImg">
                <img src="Img_d.profiles/profile_one.png" alt="Profile One" width="75%" label="hello">
                <p class="prfImg" id="user">A name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="prfImg">
                <img src="Img_d.profiles/profile_two.png" alt="Profile Two" width="75%">
                <p class="prfImg" id="user">A name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="prfImg">
                <img src="Img_d.profiles/profile_three.png" alt="Profile Three" width="75%">
                <p class="prfImg" id="user">A name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="prfImg">
                <img src="Img_d.profiles/profile_four.png" alt="Profile Foud" width="75%">
                <p class="prfImg" id="user">A name</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- button class -->
    </div>

    <div class="btn">
        <button>Manage Profiles</button>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image] on my own!*

Comment: For me, it seems to work fine with the code snippet you shared. Does it not work with real images (the code snippet was with alt text instead)?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the hover event on the parent div.

Change this:

```
.prfImg > img:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.787);
    border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.787);
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

to this

```
.prfImg:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.787);
    border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.787);
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: I tried but it hovered the border around the the image and the text. I am trying to look back and see if maybe my HTML was done wrong making the CSS code skewed?

Comment: @ZiPage change the class name of the `p` to something different.  Like `prfImg-text`